# Can I safely use popen inline?

Tags: c, stream, fopen, popen

I'm using C, not C++, and I need to open a stream with `popen()`. Normally, I would `pclose()` the pointer, but I'm not sure how in this case.

```
fgets(bufptr, bufsize, popen(cmd, "r"));
```

I would try fitting `pclose()` in there somewhere, but the return value for `pclose()` is `int` and only `popen()` returns a pointer to the stream.

Is the pointer to this stream lost? If so, can I still `pclose` it? If not, is this method inherently unsafe?

Comment: I'm just wondering if I need to save the pointer at all. If I do, I will simply `fgets(bufptr, bufsize, fp)`.

Comment: You would have to ask yourself what happens if `popen` fails. Its man page says, that it would return `NULL` in case of an error. Have you tried `fgets` with `NULL` as third parameter? It causes a SEGFAULT. Its up to you if you can live with that ;)

Comment: "Is the pointer to this stream lost". Yes it's lost. And yes it's inherently bad to do it that way - both unsafe and untidy (resource leak). So yeah, just call `popen` as a seperate statement and store the return value. That's the right way to do it.

Comment: If you want your client code to look cleaner, write a function `fillBufferFromProcess(const char*)`.